# Password reset with Filevault recovery key not working

Tags: password, filevault

My OSX machine somehow said my password was incorrect and I ended up using the recovery key to get in to the password reset step.
When I try to enter a new password and want to save that the fields just wiggle and I cannot continue. It does however somehow store the password because I cannot reset it to that one.

This system is managed using JAMF and as I said it has filevault enabled.

This video (not mine) shows what happens: https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/32075/reset-password-issue-never-seen-that-issue-check-this-video

How can I get out of this mess?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out you can ignore the shaking and select 'restart' after which the new password works. After logging in with it you'll be presented with another reset password screen but this one works.